# Redirect to new domain based on path in Haproxy

Tags: url-rewriting, haproxy

Hello and thanks ahead of time for the help.

I have a blog on my old site and I'm trying to 301 redirect all of the posts to their new location on my new site using haproxy.  For example, I want  https://www.oldsite.com/john-blog/blogpost1 to be 301 redirected to https://www.newsite.com/jill-blog/blogpost1.

https://www.oldsite.com/john-blog => https://www.newsite.com/jill-blog

```
frontend https
  option http-server-close
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https

  acl is_ob path_sub john-blog

  redirect location https://www.newsite.com/jill-blog code 301 if is_ob
```

I've figure out how to forward traffic for `/john-blog` but haven't been able to figure out how to do the rewrite so that `/john-blog/blogpost1` on the old site 301s to `/jill-blog/blogpost1` on the new site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I was able to come up with:

```
frontend https
    option http-server-close
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https

    acl old_site hdr(host) -i www.oldsite.com
    acl john_blog path_beg /john-blog
    acl jill_blog path_beg /jill-blog

    reqrep ^([^\ ]*\ /)john-blog(.*) \1jill-blog\2 if old_site john_blog
    redirect prefix https://www.newsite.com code 301 if old_site jill_blog
```

The only downside of this config is that it will also redirect `https://www.oldsite.com/jill-blog` => `https://www.newsite.com/jill-blog`. If this is an issue I can try and figure something else out.

**How is works**

I will follow and example for a request to `https://www.oldsite.com/john-blog/blogpost1`.

In this example acl `old_site` would be true, acl `john_blog` would be true and acl `jill_blog` would be false.

The `reqrep` line replaces `john-blog` with `jill-blog` only if both the `old_site` and `john_blog` acls are true, which for this example is the case. After this line the example url would be `https://www.oldsite.com/jill-blog/blogpost1`.

At this point acl `john_blog` is now no longer true but acl `jill_blog` is as the uri now begins with `/jill-blog`. acl `old_site` is still true.

The `redirect` line is in [prefix mode](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4.2-redirect%20prefix) where the redirect location is determined by the provided string with the original uri appended. In this example the provided string is `https://www.newsite.com` and the uri that gets appended is `/jill-blog/blogpost1` resulting in a reditect url of `https://www.newsite.com/jill-blog/blogpost1`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @JamesStewy, I have a similar http-redirect request but couldn't make it work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48583664/how-to-redirect-url-using-haproxy