# How to redirect url using haproxy

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, haproxy, httpd.conf

I want to redirect https://myserver/myapplication/ to https://myserver.domain.com/myapplication/ using haproxy.

This is my haproxy configuration

```
frontend LB_http
   bind 10.123.122.112:80
   reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
   default_backend LB


frontend LB_https
   bind 10.123.122.112:443 ssl crt /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.pem
   reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
   default_backend LB

backend LB
   redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
   mode http
   stats enable
   stats hide-version
   stats uri /stats
   stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
   stats auth haproxy:redhat            # Credentials for HAProxy Statistic report page.
   balance roundrobin                   # Load balancing will work in round-robin process.
   option httpchk
   option httpclose
   option forwardfor

   server myserver.domain.com myserver.domain.com:80          # backend server.
```

I have edited the config file by adding the below two lines

```
acl no_domain hdr(host) -i myserver
http-request redirect code 301 prefix %[hdr(host)].domain.com%[path] if no_domain
```

But now, when I try

> myserver/myapplication/

the url is redirecting multiple times I guess. It is redirecting me to very long url like this

> https://myserver/myapplication/myserver.domain.com/myapplication/myserver.domain.com/myapplication/myserver.domain.com/myapplication/myserver.domain.com/myapplication/myserver.domain.com/myapplication/myserver.domain.com/myapplication/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code as below and it started working as expected

```
frontend LB_http
   bind 10.123.122.112:80
   reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
   default_backend LB


frontend LB_https
   bind 10.123.122.112:443 ssl crt /usr/local/apache2/conf/server.pem
   reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
   default_backend LB

backend LB
   acl no_domain hdr(host) -i myserver
   http-request redirect code 301 prefix https:\/\/myserver.domain.com if no_domain
   redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
   mode http
   stats enable
   stats hide-version
   stats uri /stats
   stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
   stats auth haproxy:redhat            # Credentials for HAProxy Statistic report page.
   balance roundrobin                   # Load balancing will work in round-robin process.
   option httpchk
   option httpclose
   option forwardfor

   server myserver.domain.com myserver.domain.com:80          # backend server.
```

Now when I give

> myserver/myapplication

it redirects to

> https://myserver.domain.com/myapplication